# PySide's setWindowTitle does not show text in main window

Tags: python, pyside

I am reproducing the code from a manual for PySide Python; I am using python 2.7 since I understand that PySide does not work in python 3.5 yet. I am using Ubuntu Xenial as a platform. 
The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
# main app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create app
    my_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # set safety
    try:
        # create label
        appLabel = QLabel()
        appLabel.setText("Hello, world!\nLook at my first app")
        appLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        appLabel.setWindowTitle("my first app")
        appLabel.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 175)
        # show label
        appLabel.show()
        # exec
        my_app.exec_()
        sys.exit()
    except NameError:
        print("Name Error:", sys.exc_info()[1])
        pass
```

The window opens, the main text is there but there is not window text ("my first app").

What I am missing?

Thanks

G

Comment: Check on Ubuntu top bar, it should be there.

Comment: you are right! why does not come up in the window I am creating? Tx